# White Screen Of Death when Cache is cleared in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, wsod, drupal-cache

I am getting White Screen of Death while trying to clear the cache in Drupal 7 installation. In my local machine it caused me no problem. The issue started when I deployed it to server.  I tried to display the errors  using the code,
`error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);` 
 in index.php. And it shows out-of-memory error. I tried to increase the memory limit in php.ini file and it was of no use..

Anyone got any idea why this is dying when cache is cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem got solved with a single line of code in settings.php. I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');` in settings.php file and now the cache is being cleared. :)

As a reference, you can take a look at [Drupal WSOD](http://www.ubercart.org/faq/2246.)

Answer (score 1):

add following line in your apptheme

```
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

If it is not working for you, then you can use

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to clear the cache?

When `drush cache-clear` and devel/cache/clear were both blowing up for me, the "Clear all caches" method on the performance page - admin/config/development/performance - worked just fine. Your mileage may vary!

Comment: I am trying to clear the cache using the same on the administration panel, admin/config/development/performance. This gives me WSOD.